# How do I create a table in a website such that only admin can alter the values?

Tags: web-development-server

I've been building a simple static website for a travel agency, the website has a simple table of their charges/fares, since charges change on daily basis they need the table data to be changed by them easily. What is the best way to do this? I'm familiar with php and jsp. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be to build an admin page so that the administrator can login and change values.

The page could consist of a simple form to fetch and display current values and the admin could change the values and save them.

There could be one or more admins and in more complicated websites, you could configure which admins have the power to change which values etc.

You can use a proper authentication to authenticate a user to log in to the admin side. The if you need control over which admins can change a particular set of values, you need to use authorization to fine control who changes stuff.

Rather than trying to build your own authetication and authorization modules, you should try to find and use any freely available authentication and authorization modules. I am sure PHP has some. Try github.

Comment: I was planning the same. Thanks for quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase as the backend. In such a case the table data will be retrieved from firebase. Now since you only want an admin to edit/delete/add data you can use the Auth feature in firebase to disable the edit fields.
I have an exact scenario setup on my static website too hosted on Github. Check it out [here](https://kamikazechaser.github.io/intenseheat)

Comment: The table in my website is fully functional. I have just messed around with the code during tests.